# JQuery/Javascript - how to minimize duplicated code?

Tags: javascript, jquery

If I wanted to use the following code on multiple DIV#ID, how do I do so without duplicating code

```
var scrollElem = $('#div1');
scrollElem.scroll(function() {
 /* find the closest (hlisting) home listing to the middle of the scrollwindow */ 
    var scrollElemPos = scrollElem.offset();
    var newCenter = $(document.elementFromPoint(
        scrollElemPos.left + scrollElem.width()  / 2,
        scrollElemPos.top  + scrollElem.height() / 2)
    ).closest('.hlisting');
    if(newCenter.is(".HighlightRow")) return;
    $('.HighlightRow').removeClass("HighlightRow");
    newCenter.addClass('HighlightRow');
});
```

What I want to do is perform this not only on `div1`, but also on `div2`, `div3`, `div4`.

But as you note, `scrollElem` is a global variable so I can't just stick all of this code in 1 function.

Meaning, to get this to work - I would have to do:

```
// DIV 2 ---------------------------
var scrollElem2 = $('#div2');
scrollElem.scroll(function() {
 /* find the closest (hlisting) home listing to the middle of the scrollwindow */ 
    var scrollElemPos = scrollElem2.offset();
    var newCenter = $(document.elementFromPoint(
        scrollElemPos.left + scrollElem2.width()  / 2,
        scrollElemPos.top  + scrollElem2.height() / 2)
    ).closest('.hlisting');
    if(newCenter.is(".HighlightRow")) return;
    $('.HighlightRow').removeClass("HighlightRow");
    newCenter.addClass('HighlightRow');
});

// DIV 3 ---------------------------
var scrollElem3 = $('#div3');
scrollElem3.scroll(function() {
 /* find the closest (hlisting) home listing to the middle of the scrollwindow */ 
    var scrollElemPos = scrollElem3.offset();
    var newCenter = $(document.elementFromPoint(
        scrollElemPos.left + scrollElem3.width()  / 2,
        scrollElemPos.top  + scrollElem3.height() / 2)
    ).closest('.hlisting');
    if(newCenter.is(".HighlightRow")) return;
    $('.HighlightRow').removeClass("HighlightRow");
    newCenter.addClass('HighlightRow');
});
```

That's copying and pasting a lot of duplicate code.

**Question**: there must be a better way to do this. Any ideas on how to accomplish the same functionality but minimize the duplication of code.

Answer (score 4):

use multiple selector when you define the scrollElem

```
var scrollElem = $('#div1, #div2, ...');
```

and inside the function, wherever you want to use the current scrollElem use $(this)

```
var scrollElemPos = $(this).offset();
```

etc..

Comment: @ALlen, well.. instead of using `$(this)` multiple times you could create a variable like `var $this = $(this)` and use that ... that would be optimal i think..

Answer (score 2):

Put it into a function.

```
function myFunc(elem){
    var scrollElemPos = elem.offset();
    var newCenter = $(document.elementFromPoint(
        scrollElemPos.left + elem.width()  / 2,
        scrollElemPos.top  + elem.height() / 2)
    ).closest('.hlisting');
    if(newCenter.is(".HighlightRow")) return;
    $('.HighlightRow').removeClass("HighlightRow");
    newCenter.addClass('HighlightRow');
}

var scrollElem = $('#div1');
scrollElem.scroll(function() {
  myFunc($(this));
});
```

Comment: have to change the reference to scrollElem3 as it would need to be different for each object.  $(this) seems like it'd work.

Comment: Beat me to the punch. There's no reason the code given by the OP can't be put into a function. If anything, it's best to avoid global variables entirely.

Comment: What about scrollElem3 in the myFunc()?

Comment: @ty & @Allen, missed it...changed to 'elem'

Comment: Couldn't I also eliminate all together the scrollElem by doing:  $('#div1').scroll(function(){myFunc($(this));});

Comment: @Allen, if you're not using it again down the line, you absolutely could and should.

Answer (score 1):

I think a combination of the answers provided by [Gaby](https://stackoverflow.com/users/128165/gaby) and [munch](https://stackoverflow.com/users/166902/munch) would be optimal:

Use a multi-selector and `$(this)`,

```
$('#div1, #div2, ...').scroll(myFunc);
```

In combination with a predefined function:

```
function myFunc() {
    var scrollElemPos = $(this).offset();
    // etc...
}
```

Now existing functionality works as designed, and you can also call `myFunc` manually with `call` and `apply`.

```
// call myFunc with .call or .apply to set context
myFunc.call(someElement); // inside myFunc "this" will point to someElement
```

Answer (score -1):

couldn't you change the anonymous function to a named function and pass the same function to whatever.scroll?

the only thing you'd have to change would be the reference to scrollElemX.  use $(this) instead.